# Coarse Moduli space of proper Deligne-Mumford stacks

Tags: coarse-moduli-spaces, stacks, ag.algebraic-geometry

Let F be a finite type proper Deligne-Mumford Stack over a perfect field. Is it true that the coarse moduli space of F is proper?

Comment: The map from the stack to the space is a proper homeomorphism - so yes.  Brian Conrad has a "modern" proof of Keel and Mori's theorem on the existence of coarse moduli spaces which you may find interesting (and can find on his webpage).

Comment: mdeland: Your comment should be an answer.

Comment: @mdeland Doesn't this show only the other direction, namely that a DM-stack with proper coarse moduli is proper as well?